# entity framework. relating many to many instance as single instance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to construct the relationships for my models as in the example below :

**College**
CollegeId
CollegeName

**Course**
CourseId
Course

**Student**
StudentId
StudentName

the easy bit is
College has many courses.
Student can have many courses at many colleges.

the bit where I get stuck is the course status

**courseStatus**
CourseId
StudentId
StatusCode

this isn't itself complicated. but I want to be able to list out a list of courses for a given student with their current status :

How do I do this?

**Course**
CourseId
Course
*CourseStatus*

this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You only need College , Course and Student. There has to be relationships between Course and College and Student and Course. Try creating the tables with FKs first. Then you will understand the entity structure better.

Comment: I think you misunderstand.... there is one course with many students. each student may be on many courses. 

For each course a student is on I want to record their status. e.g. completed.

**StudentCourseAssingment**
StudentID
CourseID

The join table assigns the students / courses. For each of these there will be a status.

Comment: Ok. StudentCourse makes sense. So what was your problem? Sounds like you already know what you want.

Comment: How do I navigate the status. e.g. I show the student and I want to list the course they are on with their status.

Student.Courses
Course.Status